# How to make Distinct... More distinct?

Tags: c#, linq

Ok, aside from the silly title.  I have a query pulling back distinct values but it is including the `departmentID` column instead of the `departmentName` column as distinct.  Which makes me sometimes causes duplicates.

```
ViewBag.DepartmentList = docs.Select(m => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)m.departmentID).Trim(),
                Text = m.departmentName
            })
            .Distinct(); //  Fill the viewbag with a unique list of 'Department's from the table.
```

Here is what the docs has inside it:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdPIl.png)
[image]

If it helps at all, the `departmentID` is a primary key.  so `departmentID 1` will always point to the same name and so on.

Comment: Your problem is that you're calling Distict on the SelectListItem and not on your query first. Try calling it on your query and then taking the results of the query and putting it into your select list.

Comment: @Kittoes that gave the the duplicates the same as having distinct at the end.

Comment: `var query = (from p in docs
              select new {
                  p.departmentId,
                  p.departmentName
              }).Distict();`

Comment: @Kittoes let me play with that a bit.

Comment: I've run into this in the past and came up with this: [Enhancing Distinct With The PredicateEqualityComparer](http://msmvps.com/blogs/paulomorgado/archive/2010/04/08/linq-enhancing-distinct-with-the-predicateequalitycomparer.aspx) [Enhancing Distinct With The SelectorEqualityComparer](http://msmvps.com/blogs/paulomorgado/archive/2010/04/09/linq-enhancing-distinct-with-the-selectorequalitycomparer.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `IEqualityComparer`

```
class MyComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T> where T : SelectListItem
{
    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        return x.Value == y.Value ;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return obj.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

then your code

```
ViewBag.DepartmentList = docs.Select(m => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)m.departmentID).Trim(),
            Text = m.departmentName
        })
        .Distinct(new MyComparer<SelectListItem>()).ToList();
```